# Flash a fluorescent tube

Tags: light, flash

Is it possible to build a circuit to make a fluorescent tube flash on and off for use as a lighting effect? If so, how?

Also, if the above is possible, can it be used to flash more than one tube at a time without having to repeat the control circuitry for each tube?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try an EHT inverter circuit and avoid messing around with mains power, ballasts and starter circuits entirely. I used inverters salvaged from old fluorescent camping lights with some larger 4ft tubes for stage special effects a few years back. In my case the fact that the tubes didn't glow at full brightness was not an issue. I found this article which may be of use: http://talkingelectronics.com/projects/FluorescentInverter/FluorescentInverter.html

Comment: This is great.... exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: The article in your link is a very nice hack! I really like the circuit and its description! Just two notes: (i) Ideally, there should be dots on the primary and feedback (auxiliary) windings of the transformer: Top end (pri) and on the Left end (aux). The dot on the secondary could be anywhere because the load (fluo lamp) is non-polar. (ii) Even though I like using a ferrite rod from an AM radio for an experiment like this, I wouldn't take this circuit to a lab for testing electro-magnetic emissions. The screen of the frequency-domain diagram of test receiver would be very bright...

Answer (score 6):

Well, first of all, you need to have electrodes hot all the time.
If you will try to heat them at the moment of pulse you will kill your tubes in a matter of hours.

Then you can turn on your main *constant-current* (ballast circuit) power supply for whatever time you need as long as it's fast enough to stabilize during your 1-10-100ms pulses.

You can use 1 constant-current device for multiple lamps if you connect then in series, but the required voltage will be much higher, so I believe it's cheaper to have 1 device per lamp.

Comment: If you want to get fancy, you can switch the HV after the ballast, which will let you flash them for however fast your power devices will go.

Comment: Or better yet, with a very high-voltage pulse, you can start them with the filaments cold.

Comment: With these nice very high-voltage pulses you surely can flash it, but doing so with cold electrodes will quickly evaporate them.

Comment: So if the voltage is high enough, it's not necessary to heat the electrodes? What voltage do I need for this to work?

Comment: I've heard you can put a copper strip around the tube near one of the electrodes and use this some how to trigger the tube to light up... has anyone else heard of this before?

Comment: @BG100: If you pulse high voltage on cold electrodes, top layer of metal just evaporates and tube dies soon. Using copper strip around - yes, that works. It ionize the gas, and in fact, if you put RF frequency on it, it will glow just because of this RF.

Comment: Hmmm. It appears I'm confusing some research I did on xenon tubes with what I remember about fluorescents. Nevermind.

Comment: Oh, also, the breakdown voltage would be many kilovolts.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use the LED-based tube replacements and a microcontroller of some sort to simulate the flashing patterns you need.

Comment: Yes.... but this will be way too expensive. Fluorescent tubes are cheap!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve a rapidly flashing fluorescent light during a stage talent show using a light dimmer. You can buy one that goes in a wall socket if that's what you need. At around 35% - 40% power there will be a certain moment where it just flashes extremely fast, any % other than that it will just emit less or more light, depending on the %.

This is actually not very safe and I don't have any idea what long-term impact it may have on the ballast or the actual tube, but for me, it worked.